# Get Windows Icons and File Type Names in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, icons, file-type

I am trying to get the native windows icons and file type names for a file I am reading in using OpenFileDialog.  The FileInfo doesn't contain this.  I need something similar to shell32.SHGetFileInfo and szTypeName, but I believe shell32 has permission problems with silverlight.  Is there a way for me to do this?